# Why doesnt 127.255.255.255 work as loopback

Tags: loopback

I recently read that you can use anything starting with 127 as a loopback ip. I was messing around and I found that most of them work, however 127.255.255.255 does not. Is this because it is at the top of the range? I am testing it with nginx on ubuntu 14.04 but I suspect there is a very important reason for this and it is not just a random anomaly.

Comment: Well, that would be the broadcast address for that network

Comment: this might be a better question for ServerFault or SuperUser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember correctly from my study years loopback can be configured on any address/network you want. And 127.0.0.0 and 127.255.255.255 are probably network and broadcast addresses.

Answer (score 1):

According to what I have been told, even though RFC3330 defines 127.0.0.0/8 as available loopback addresses, the implementation of this in an OS usually only allows for 127.0.0.1. In order to use another address it must be added manually (or via script for a larger block), such as

> sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.255.255.255 up

Comment: If I'm not wrong 127.0.0.0/8 network is reserved for loopback but it's up to OS to chose what address will be used as loobpback address. But you are not limited only to reserved network and can configure any address as loopback.

Answer (score 1):

On windows cmd type "route print"

You would see:

```
    Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
    127.0.0.0                255.0.0.0          On-link       127.0.0.1    306
```

This tells us that, although 127.0.0.0 is technically an IP, here it is treated as a network ID and is only used for performing matches in routing table. The interface is 127.0.0.1 **always**.

For 127.255.255.255, this is directed broadcast address which is disabled in practical conditions as it may lead to network congestion which results in Denial of service. So security issues.

Pinging any IP in range [127.0.0.1, 127.255.255.254] will give a loopback reply.
But 127.0.0.0 and 127.255.255.255 won't.

Answer (score 0):

127.255.255.255 is for broadcasting purpose.

Comment: Some extra information would be nice since this was already said in the comments...

Answer (score 0):

you can configure ip in config file. default is 127.0.0.1